# How could $\nabla_\vec{v} f(x,y) = \nabla f(x, y) \cdot \vec{v}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient), $\nabla_\vec{v} f(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y) \cdot \vec{v}$ and $\nabla f \overset{\text{def}}{=} (\frac{\partial f}{dx}, \frac{\partial f}{dy})$, but if I define $f$ as:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}g(x,y)&\text{if $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

then $\nabla f(0, 0) = (0,0)$ so $\nabla_{(1,1)}f(0,0) = (0,0) \cdot (0,0) = 0$. But this contradicts the definition of the directional derivative, $\nabla_\vec{v}f(\vec{x}) \overset{\text{def}}{=} \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(\vec{x}+h\vec{v})-f(\vec{x})}{h}$, which means that $\nabla_{(1,1)}f(0,0)$ could be anything, not just $0$.

Is Wikipedia wrong? Is there some kind of condition that there are no "cuts" in the function such that $\nabla_\vec{v} f(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y) \cdot \vec{v}$?

Comment: Sure there is a condition: differentiability

Comment: Why is $\nabla f(0, 0)$ equal to $(0, 0)$?

Comment: @MichaelLee: Because the derivatives when x=0 and y changes and when y=0 and x changes are both 0.

Comment: @Miguel: Doesn't differentiable just mean that the derivative exists?

Comment: The existence of partial derivatives does not imply the existence of the gradient vector. You need differentiability for that.

Comment: Consider the counterexample $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},& (x, y)\neq (0, 0) \\ 0,& (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$ This has partial derivatives at $(0, 0)$, but is not even continuous, let alone differentiable, at that point. Therefore, $\nabla f(0, 0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelLee: Oh, I see. I'm learning multivariable calculus on my own and neither Khan Academy nor Wikipedia seem to mention anywhere that the function must be differentiable (or even define differentiability for multi-variable functions) for the gradient to exist.

Comment: [Here's](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_partial_derivatives_not_implies_differentiable) a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: And [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative) is the criterion for differentiability that you're looking for.

Comment: @user485573 +1 for learning multivariable calculus. However... call me old-fashioned, but why not use a (good) book? I use the one by Adam's but there are plenty...

Comment: I'm a fan of Stewart in particular (don't buy the newer, overpriced editions, though).